# Angry birds spinning toy working

Tags: led, batteries, energy-harvesting

I recently purchased the Angry birds spinning toy which works like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ncE_cehGGs). The hand crank basically rotates and from the power generated,Dissecting the product into various parts, I came across certain elements which I have failed to understand and seek to get more clarity into it:

[image]

1. Is there any power generation that is harvested through the turning mechanism that is utilised by this toy? I strongly suspect this because on close inspection, I could find magnet and a copper coil winding as shown below. I fail to understand how there is a relative flux difference which is used for power generation, as the whole top spins on its axis.
2. What do the recoil springs on the LED Driver circuit do?
3. There are three wires- yellow, red and green coming out from the battery. How are they used to charge/discharge the battery?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where does the green wire go?

Comment: It lifted from the center between the two other battery wires.

Comment: @RJR The green wire goes to the LED driving circuit. It actually came out of the solder when I tried removing opening it.

Comment: The round part with "JV" stamped on it is a speaker, and thus probably does little to no energy harvesting.

Answer (score 1):

There's no power generation. The 'spring' is just a contact that closes when the spring bends under the centrifugal force when you spin the toy.
Not sure why there are three battery connections - can to show how the batteries connect to the three wires? The circuit might use two different voltages but that seems unlikely...

Comment: If there's no power generation, why are there magnets and coils connected to the crank?

Comment: Yes! I just checked the centrifugal force affecting the spring, it works. By compressing it, its lighting up the LED. But I am not able to get the power generation from the magnets and why there are three wires coming from the battery?

Comment: sorry - I don't see the magnet and coils - maybe I'm missing something? You don't mean the speaker I assume?

Comment: What batteries does it take? is it something like 3x AAA? And is at least one of the LEDs blue or white? It may be that they are pulling off the batteries at two different points in order to get two different voltages, one for the electronics (3V) and one for the LEDs (4.5V). This is a cheap and nasty way to get two different voltages while saving the cost of a regulator.